# Dynamically load shared library while running

Tags: c++

I'd like to know if it is possible to load a Linux shared library (extension being .so) into a program that is already running. T

he library that I'm wanting to load is a plugin to modify aspects of the program.

I'd like to load the plugin at any time while the program is running.

**EDIT 10/22: This question is years old and I sincerely apologise for the sheer poor quality and utter stupidity of this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the core concepts of shared library. You should start by looking at `dlopen` functions and examples